# how to send files by email from azure blob storage using azure logic apps?

Tags: containers, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to get the files from container in azure storage and to send it to my personnel email using logic app :
this is my template in logic app designer :

[image]

[image]

[image]

and this is my container :

[image]

and this the error that I got in my template in logic app designer :
The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.

this is the screenshot of the error :

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of the error itself?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the error on the question description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing from our end while in `Get blob content (V2)` you've mentioned Blob to be 'Name', but it refers to mention path to the blob. Hence, This was working after changing Blob from `Name` to `Path`.

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved.
But when I put 4 files I receive 16 emails, 4 emails contain the same file
When I put 3 files I receive 9 emails, 3 emails contain the same file
any suggestion to solve this problem ?